# add css class sharepoint 2010 webpart

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to add a custom CSS class to a Sharepoint 2010 webpart? I need to custom style a website and the standard Sharepoint classes are driving me nuts. I'm used to working with Drupal, there i use a module that allows me to add a custom class to a block. This allows me to create classes such as "BlueSidebarBlock" "Orange SidebarBlock" "ContentBlock1" "ContentBlock2" etc. When i create a new block i can easily choose one of the styles to use so i don't have to custom style each new block.

This is what i want to do in this SharePoint site. I can only use CSS and maybe add a module or addon, no jquery or custom code or anything like that. Is it possible to achieve that when i create a new webpart, there's an option that allows me to add a custom CSS class that applies to just that webpart on that specific page?

I know i can style using the webpartID, but since it's a large site that would mean a huge amount of CSS. Hope my blabbering makes some sence!